# incorrect encoding serving binary (pdf) file through ClassPathResource in Spring

Tags: java, spring, pdf, encoding, binary

I have been struggling with the following problem for two days and can not get my head around it.

I am trying to serve a static pdf in a Spring Boot rest application. It should be very straight forward but I just cannot get it to work.

First I simply placed the pdf in the resource folder and tried to load it directly from the javascript code, like this:

```
var newWindow = window.open(/pdf/test.pdf, '');
```

That resulted in a new window with a pdf not showing any content.

Saving the pdf to disk from the browser and investigating the contents revealed that they were different from the original. I am showing screenshots from Atom for both (original first), in ISO-8859-1 encoding:

[image: snippet from original pdf]
[image: same part, pdf as saved from browser]

My conclusion so far: Spring or Tomcat somehow changed the binary content. Maybe it is encoding it? In Base64?

Then I tried to implement it on the server side, to see what is going on. I implemented a rest controller that would serve the pdf contents.

An interesting find is that it initially gave the same results as with the direct approach. I used the classPathResource to get a handle to the pdf file.

But when I load the pdf directly from a path using FileInputStream and File, it works. See code below:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test.pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

        /* does not work
        ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource("test.pdf");
        InputStream is = pdfFile.getInputStream();
        */

        /* works */
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("z:\\downloads\\test.pdf"));


        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        response.flushBuffer();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
}
```

What is going on here? Why is Spring/Tomcat changing the binary data when using ClassPathResource or when serving it directly?

I would be grateful for some help here. I cannot use a direct path because the pdf will be in a jar file eventually, so I will need ClassPathResource or some other ResourceLoader.

Comment: This can be reproduced simply by opening a PDF file that has been packaged into a JAR file created with Maven. I was searching for hours about charset encoding issues, but your solution is so efficient. I think you should accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, finally I found the culprit and it was in a completely unexpected corner.

I am using IntelliJ with Maven for this project and as it turns out, IntelliJ corrupted the content of the pdf when copying it to the /target folder. And of course tomcat was serving this file, not the one in the /src folder... so it had nothing to do with ClassPathResource or Spring. It was Maven.

I had to disable filtering for (binary) pdf in the pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

which solved the issue. Now a direct request of the file (localhost:8080/test.pdf) as well as the rest controller approach work. @Andy Brown: thanks for the quick reply although it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Writing directly to the response output stream might be nuking your ability to set headers. I tested your code with `curl` as the user agent and `Content-Type` was missing from the response which would cause your client to apply a transformation and mess up the content.

Rewriting your body to look like this will fix the problem:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/test.pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
  public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile() {
    try {

      ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource("test.pdf");

      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=test.pdf");

      InputStream is = pdfFile.getInputStream();

      return new ResponseEntity<>(
          new InputStreamResource(is),
          headers,
          HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
  }
```

I get from the fact that you're streaming responses that these are potentially large and you care about efficiency. The best way to do this is to return an implementation of `StreamingResponseBody` in which you implement the `write` method using a fast NIO stream-to-stream copy.